# Symmetric Algebra Ideal

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

Given a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ one can construct the tensor algebra $T(V)$ of $V$, where $$T(V)=F\oplus V\oplus(V\otimes V)\oplus(V\otimes V\otimes V)\oplus\dots$$

The symmetric algebra $S(V)$ on $V$ is the quotient algebra $T(V)/I$ where **$I$ is the two-sided ideal in $T(V)$ generated by all $x\otimes y-y\otimes x$ $\forall x,y\in V$.**

This is taken from Humphreys Lie Algebra text. I don't understand what the words in bold mean.

**Question:** Is $I$ the set $\{x\otimes y-y\otimes x:x,y\in V\}$? Or something else?

Comment: It is the ideal generated by that set (as it says). I.e. the smallest two-sided ideal containing all those elements.

Comment: And "ideal" here is the usual (two-sided) ideal from ring theory -- recall that an algebra (such as the tensor algebra) is something that is simultaneously a ring and a vector space.